# r- convert a word to numbers

Tags: r, numbers, letter

I'm trying to convert a string "abcd" into a string of numbers in which each number will indicate the position of that specific letter in the alphabet, in this case this is needed: "1234". Is there a function to do this in R ?

I tried this:

```
str2int <- function(x) {
   match(x, letters[1:26])
}
str2int("abcd")
```

this didn't work since there are multiple characters in the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is actually a string with no spaces etc which should be preseved and just a series of lowercase letters, you could use `charToRaw` and then convert to numeric and subtract 96.

The reason you need to subtract 96 is because the `as.numeric(chartoRaw(x))` gives the position of the characters on the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/), and a-z starts at position 97 on that table.

```
test <- paste(letters, collapse = '')
test
# [1] "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

library(magrittr)

test %>% 
  charToRaw %>% 
  as.numeric %>% 
  '-'(96) %>% 
  paste(collapse = '')
# [1] "1234567891011121314151617181920212223242526"
```

Edit: @akrun suggests a better method below. You can replace `charToRaw %>% as.numeric` with `utf8toInt`.

Comment: Could you explain `'-'(96)`?

Comment: Added explanation

Answer (score 2):

We can use `strsplit` inside the function

```
str2int <- function(x) {
        x1 <- strsplit(x, "")[[1]]
        paste(match(x1, letters), collapse="")
 }
str2int("abcd")
#[1] "1234"
```

---

Or another option is `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn(".", ~ match(x, letters), "abcd")
#[1] "1234"
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another option is `chartr`

```
TestString = "abcd"

chartr(paste(letters[1:10], collapse=''), 
    paste(c(1:9,0), collapse=''), TestString)
```